# TextNoteType text_size minimal value

Tags: text, size, revit

I am writing a revit pluging.

I need to change the text_size of a textnotetype inside a viewplan, following a user input.

the textnotetype height has limited lo=wer and upper values.

I want to control the user input to respect this limits and avoid an error message from revit, so how can I find,read or compute the minimal and maximal values of a textnotetype height ?

Thanks in advance

Luc

Answer (score 0):

I see no such limitations in the [Text Note Type Properties](https://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2020/ENU/?guid=GUID-4E9F0CC4-5447-46A1-B291-F1D93F72DE4C).

How do you see those in the user interface?

What error message do you observe?

Comment: If I do textElementType.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.TEXT_SIZE).Set(size); then size is to small or to big (or if size equal 0) then revit display an advert box

Comment: the advert message : Value is out of range, !please enter a number between 0.2524mm and 413.3702 mm
and the transaction is roolbacked

Answer (score 0):

0.2 millimetres seems ridiculously small to me, and 400 millimetres ridiculously large.

In that case, I would say you can easily solve this problem by adding your own limits that are perfectly sensible, e.g., 2 mm minimum and 40 mm maximum. These sensible limits will then also protect the user also from hitting the ridiculous limits imposed by Revit.